# Eclipse project not built on Mac due to 'A resource exists with a different case' error

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am trying to following instructions to import android java source to
eclipse on mac:

http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

I did create a new partition ('Mac OS Extended, case sensitive, journaled) on Mac.
I was able to build android sdk successfully at command line.

But when I try to create a new eclipse project and I get this error
which prevents eclipse from building the android source:

```
The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different
case: '/android/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/
android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes/MANIFEST.mf'.". 
Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may
be inconsistent android
```

Can you please tell me how can to fix my problem?

Comment: The link is giving me a 404 atm.

Comment: Anyway, I have the same error on Windows.  Neither Refactor -> Rename the namespace with the different case, nor renaming the folder corresponding to the namespace would fix the problem for me.

Comment: @apollodude217 I had to make the package name written in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, and my package name under the `src/` dir match the case on Windows. Double-checked, becuase hard to spot. it solved for me.

Comment: yinglcs did it solve for you? you could accept a solution if it did. :)

Answer (score 22):

I just ran into this issue.  It occurs when you have a case mismatch on package names.  I resolved it by closing Eclipse and reconciling all package names in my project folder (under bin, gen and src) as well as in my AndroidManifest.xml.  Once everything matched, I reopened Eclipse, did a Clean and Build and the error went away.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this problem when I had 2 seperate packages with different case defined in same project

src/main -> com.mycompany.project.DAO

src/test > com.mycompany.project.dao

Actually the 2nd package was for JUnit test cases & should not have been on build path. When I removed the 2nd package from build path (rightclick src/test -> remove from build path), this error was gone.

Comment: This was the problem with mine. Legacy code, nothing to do with me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just check your Manifest file. The package name/path should be correct. Then just delete R.java file, and clean the project. If dat doesnt solve the problem, close eclipse, and start again.
I faced same issue on windows.

Comment: I had a capitalization error in my AndroidManifest.xml file.  Notes: 1.) I didn't have to delete the R.java file and 2.) it was the AndroidManifest.xml file in the root, not in the bin directory (probably something that is obvious if you understand elipse)  hth.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path.  Under "Source Project" tab check the case of the word "BIN".  if BIN is in caps then make it the same as it is in your project tree hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for being helpful - just remember: a) this is not a place to offer services b) don't invent words like _ur_ ...

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your jar file.
remove the jar and add correct jar.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the same problem.

Clean project and Delete R file.

Restart eclipse, then check "Problems" tab

I found two R file is mismatch, correct it and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was "switch workspace" to a new one. 
(because the old one was contaminated
)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when importing an existing project into Eclipse. I named the new project package `com.example.myproject` but the old activity was referencing `package com.example.MyProject` (notice the uppercasing difference). After I renamed the package the project built fine.

Answer (score 0):

**1_** match "package" parameter in the manifest XML tag exactly with the package name in Src Java files.

com.example.myapp **is not** com.example.MyApp

**2_** delete all things in Gen folder

**3_** Project -> Clean

enjoy **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Tried many of the above resolutions myself. I found it was better to just remove the application from my workspace and re-Import it. Resolved itself after that.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this happened to me recently.  I renamed the project in eclipse from ABC to Abc.   I found the problem in the hidden ".project" file ... It still had the uppercase variant "ABC".  I change the case in the .project file to Abc ... And all is well.